# Call a function to a variable that's within another function that's from another template file WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm working with the WordPress customizer and I need users to edit their API key in the customizer. The problem is each function needs to operate from a separate template file. I need a variable that's within a function to call a function that's in another template file that can produce single quotes around it ''.

What works hardcoded:

```
//api.php

function api() {
//this is a random API key
 $api_key = '000000000000000000';
}


//customizer.php
//This is what I need to call to $api_key. It actually doesn't do anything on its own 

function newsletter_api_key($newsletter_api) {
  $newsletter_api = get_option('newsletter_api_key_setting', '');
  return $newsletter_api;
}
add_action('wp_head', 'newsletter_api_key');

function customizer_newsletter($wp_customize) {
  $wp_customize->add_panel('newsletter_key_panel', array(
    'priority'      => 120,
    'title'         => esc_html__('Newsletter Settings', 'testWP'),
  ));
  /*
  Section for Api & ID
  */
  $wp_customize->add_section('newsletter_key_section', array (
    'title'       => esc_html__('MailChimp API & ID Key', 'testWP'),
    'description' => esc_html__('Enter you Api and ID to start receiving subscribers', 'testWP'),
    'priority'    => 1,
    'panel'       => 'newsletter_key_panel',
  ));
  //API setting / control
  $wp_customize->add_setting('newsletter_api_key_setting', array(
    'default'           => '',
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    'transport'         => 'refresh',
    'type'              => 'option',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses',
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_control('newsletter_api_key_control', array(
    'settings'  => 'newsletter_api_key_setting',
    'label'     => esc_html__('API Key', 'testWP'),
    'section'   => 'newsletter_key_section',
    'type'      => 'text',
    'description' => esc_html__('Enter your API key here.', 'testWP'),
  ));

}
add_action('customize_register', 'customizer_newsletter');
```

What I tried:

```
function api() {
//this is a random API key
 $api_key = newsletter_api_key($newsletter_api);
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong please? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't show how the API key is consumed. And your `API()` don't even return a thing.

Comment: Can you be more clear of how you want things to behave (i.e. how certain line of code to output), and how it is behaving instead?

Comment: do you have value in `get_option('newsletter_id_key_setting')`?

Comment: @Vel Yes, it's a customizer input option, similar to what I used for another customizer option but i feel it wouldn't be helpful posting all of the code from both files.

Comment: did you print this value `$newsletter_api = get_option('newsletter_id_key_setting', '');` and check inside the `wp_head` hook?

Comment: Also did you get any error like undefined funcationn call on `api.php`?

Comment: @KoalaYeung The custom customizer function above outputs whatever the user types in the wordpress customizer, it's just a simple text field that comes from another php file. I just need to figure out how link that function's return output to the variable $api_key Also updated code for clarity.

Comment: @Vel Nope, no errors and print does not work either. I wonder if it's worth just calling from the "customizer_newsletter" function above then getting the option I need, but then again, I still would not know how to return that output option either.

Comment: What does your `get_option('newsletter_id_key_setting', '');` return? Can you `var_dump` and see if the output make sense to you?

Comment: @koalaYeung My apologies, it's supposed to be get_option('newsletter_api_key_setting', ''); I seem to have pasted in the wrong option whilst making this post. Ok, I'll give it a go